# Module development with distutils and ipython

Tags: python-3.x, module, ipython, distutils

What is a typical workflow for developing a module in python3?

Right now, I'm writing some code, then :

```
  python3 setup.py sdist
  python3 setup.py install
```

And in ipython :

```
  %run myCodeUsingMyModule
```

Also, it seems that I have to ctrl+D ipython and relaunch it to get the module reloaded properly (which pretty much negates all the advantages of ipython). It's very unpractical.

How to get this right?

Comment: You can avoid the reinstallation bit by executing ``pip install -e .`` in your module's directory. This will allow you to modify it in-place.

Comment: reloading a module into a running interpreter flawlessly is pretty much impossible. Ideally, the workflow for developing a module doesn't involve using it interactively much at all, though, so this shouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: You could try the [autoreload extension](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) for IPython. It will reload the file whenever it changes.